# Custom 404 Error Messages ASP.NET Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, redirect, http-status-code-404

Anyone know how to set the custom 404 Error pages that the Visual Studio Development Server uses?

I know how to get it to work if I set is as a local IIS server and then setup the custom 404 pages in IIS. But I want to actually change them on the local VS development server so that when I test the application in Visual studio's Development server, it just works.

I'm assuming its a setting in VS.

I'm currently running VS 2010.

I've already added the custom 404 redirect for .aspx pages in the web.config. 
Now I need to figure out to change the error redirect for all other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just set up an application on your local IIS, or use that "IIS Express" option that vs 2010 provides:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

You could also use a "mock config" approach, but this strikes me as too much work.  [Testing Methods with Reference to Web.Config in .Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587516/testing-methods-with-reference-to-web-config-in-net-c-sharp)

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple setting in Visual Studio for its local development server. If there isn't I probably won't do it. I need something that can be worked on by every developer on the team without having to setup there site each time they work on it.

Comment: @matwonk that makes sense, but are you aware how easy it is to set up IIS Express in VS 2010?  Right click on the project and "Use IIS Express", and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but you can set it up in your web.config as follows:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="On">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="notfound.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
```

and have a html file called notfound.html

References:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/09/24/creating-custom-error-pages-in-asp-net-applications.aspx